# possible risk when inserting multiple data into database

Tags: c#, mysql, client-server

I have a server-client program with a database.
The client sends data to the server and the server saves the data into a database.
Now the question is if more than one client sends data to the server at the same time and the server wants to write it into the database, could there be a problem?

For example: 
client1 calls a method:

```
client.save_data(data1);
```

client2 calls a method:

```
client.save_data(data2);
```

And the server tries:

```
save_data(data){
  sql.insert_intoDB(data);
}
insert_intoDB(data)
{
  //not real code, just to show what i mean
   query = "insert into tablename values "+data;
   query.execute;
}
```

What is a good way to handle this in c#? 
Or is there no risk at all?

thx, best regards.

Comment: Read something about transactions and locks (if necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could there be a problem?

In general, yes, this problem is known as Concurrency. Different databases handle this problem in different ways. It's usually more a concern when dealing with updates rather than inserts.

I think most, if not all, database engines would handle each insert in isolation so you shouldnt have to worry about it. However, to be on the safe side you should always use Transactions so you can rollback if anything *does* go wrong.

I would recommend using a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) if your using C#.

Comment: thank you. I googled transaction and found a good example: ` 
      SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("connstringhere");
      SqlTransaction transaction;

      db.Open();
      transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
      try 
      {
         new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TransactionDemo " +
            "(Text) VALUES ('Row1');", db, transaction)
            .ExecuteNonQuery();
           transaction.Commit();
      } 
      catch (SqlException sqlError) 
      {
         transaction.Rollback();
      }
      db.Close(); `

Comment: @Manuel See my updated answer, you should probably gear more towards using `TransactionScope` rather than `Transaction` directly. It's a lot more flexible and doesn't require the `try...catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just inserting data, then there are no concurrency issues possible. The insert operations are queued and inserted in the order received by the database engine, which is always linear.